# iBeacon monitoring multiple beacons with same UUID and different major, minor

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, bluetooth, ibeacon

I have multiple iBeacons with the same UUID but different major and minor numbers. It can be different combinations for major and minor, but the UUID stays the same. Say for example,

- device #1 - UUID xyz, major 1, minor 1
- device #2 - UUID xyz, major 1, minor 2
- device #3 - UUID xyz, major 2, minor 1
- .....
- device #n - UUID xyz, major 10, minor 1

Also, these iBeacons are located in close proximities, ranging from 1 - 50 feet. Therefore, their regions can intersect with each other.

In my iOS app, I want to detect all the iBeacons with the same UUID in the area and then iterate through them and read major and minor of each to detect which one of them have been detected.

Can I use 
`init(proximityUUID: UUID, 
identifier: String)` with my UUID and then iterate through them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different iOS CoreLocation APIs and you'll need to use the first one for this purpose:

**1. Beacon Ranging** (What you want)

You call `locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)` with a region definition that leaves major and minor nil.  The constructor you show `init(proximityUUID: UUID, 
identifier: String)` does exactly that.

This will give you a callback to `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)` one time per second with an array of all `CLBeacon` objects that match your region definition.  You can iterate over this array to see all of them.

**2. Beacon Monitoring** (What you do not want)

You call `locationManager.startMonitoring(region: region)` with a region definition that leaves major and minor nil.

This will give you a callback to `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)` or the equivalent didExitRegion method each time at least *one* beacon matching the region definition appears, or *all* the beacons matching the region disappear.

This will not let you iterate over all matching beacons as the callback only includes the region definition not the list of matched beacons.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. If I want to know whether one of the iBeacons is out of range, since I don't listen to `didExitRegion` callback, should I periodically call `startMonitoring` to manually see whether I've left a region with a particular Major and Minor ?

Comment: No, the API does not work that way.  If you want to know whether a particular major minor has disappeared you must set up a new region to monitor that once the specific beacon is ranged, but you must do this only once.  But be aware you are limited to a max of 20 monitoring regions, so you must not go over that limit and must stop monitoring after each disappears..  A better way is to keep track of the last timestamp you saw each major minor combo, and fire your out of range logic when one timestamp is over, say, 10 seconds in the past.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the Beacon Monitoring is every efficient, specially suited for listening to beacons while the app is not active. A good practice is to monitor beacons and start ranging when the monitoring detects a beacon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you definitely can! You will not get new delegate notifications when another iBeacon is detected unless you create multiple listeners with different IDs but once you are in the Region of a given UUID, you can iterate through all beacons within range and get their major and minor